# simple format apn

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I read in apple push notification service guidelines that:

> With the simple format, if you send a notification packet that is
>   malformed in some way—for example, the payload exceeds the stipulated
>   limit—APNs responds by severing the connection.

But what if the message (simple format) is correct? Will APNs mantain the connection if I send keep alive packets? I don't want to establish a very large number of connections because this may be seen as DOS.

Comment: Naturally you'd open one connection to the push server and then send your message to your device list - which is in a loop, but the connection creation need not be. The guideline quote you have posted refers to exceeding the 256 byte limit for a payload (in the docs) or if the payload body has not been created properly. (eg, syntax error)

Comment: so the connection can be kept alive if i understood you correctly

Comment: Yes, but remember if you start sending payloads to the APNS server and then suddenly send a malformed one, it will sever the connection as the quote says, so you may also want to build in a "try again" mechanism to account for this happening.

Comment: good. The point is that with many messages i can't open a connection per message, since it can be viewed as DOS, but i can't either keep the connection up forever..seems to me a trade of is good solution. if you put it into an answer i will make it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashed up version of my comments, with more detail:

- Open a single connection to the APNS server, connect to your SQL (or similar) database of device ID's (officially: device token, not UDID) and iterate through these - creating the payload and then sending this to the APNS server.
- You may also consider checking how far along your device list you are, so that if the connection is severed between you and the APNS server (or something else occurs) then you can try again.
- If an error does occur, before severing the connection the APNS server will return an error-response packet. More information on this can be found in Table 5-1 of the docs, [link here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html).

Here's a sample of the details in my first point:

```
// connect to your MySQL database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");

// select a database
mysql_select_db("my_database", $con);

// run a query to grab your device tokens
$result = mysql_query("SELECT device_tokens FROM some_table");

// set your message
$msg = 'important update';

// create the payload
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => array('body' => $msg, 'action-loc-key' => 'Read'));

// convert to JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// setup APNS connection
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'password');

// open a connection to the APNS server
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $deviceToken = $row['device_tokens'];
    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage, strlen($apnsMessage));
}

// close APNS connection
fclose($apns);

// close database connection
mysql_close($con);
```

... and remember to switch between sandbox or live push servers in the URL in the code above.