# iOS Push Notification - How many can I send from my server in a minute?

Tags: ios, performance, apple-push-notifications

I'm planning to update my app with push support.
I connect to the Apple server with a php script and send all the pushs at once, the close the connection.

How many can I send in a minute? Do you guys have any experience with that?

All the best,
John

PS:
Can you recommend pushwoosh.com or urbanairship.com ? How fast do they deliver Pushs?

Comment: In theory you could send billions; but your server IP would get blacklisted by Apple for breaching the guidelines, section 5. https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html I recommend you visit the websites you have listed for answers to that. Also note there is no guarantee a message will be pushed to a device. It's all in the guide http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: Let's say I have 100.000 users in my database and everyone should get a push notification. How long would that take to send?

Comment: You can batch them all off to Apple without problem, assuming no problems at your server end, but it's then up to Apple to deliver them. It could take any length of time for this to occur and there is no guarantee of a message reaching a device.

Comment: So how many can I send in a minute? What's the limitation Apple gives (maybe their server isn't fast enough / something else)?

Comment: I use this regular PHP script to process mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019077/simple-format-apn/12028091#12028091 Admittedly only dealing with small numbers of devices, I send them off in this fashion and let Apple do the real work. You could test the script on your hardware and remove the line pushing to Apple if you're looking for solid answers re: quantities per minute. Else for better tracking and stats, there's this from UA http://urbanairship.com/products/push-messaging#analyze

Answer (score 1):

Here's what Apple say regarding push speed in their [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) :

> **Push Notification Throughput and Error Checking**
>
> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs. The iOS 6.1
>   press release stated that APNs has sent over 4 trillion push
>   notifications since it was established. It was announced at WWDC 2012
>   that APNs is sending 7 billion notifications daily.
>
> If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second,
>   your server might benefit from improved error handling logic.

We can assume from this quote that you should be able to send at least 9000 notifications per second.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try using one of the many push notifications services urban, parse, push.io and many more.
I'm using www.pushapps.mobi and the rate is 2000-3000 push per second.