# push to ios php performance

Tags: php, ios, performance, push-notification

I'm working on a live-Ticker app for an Icehockey Team and I try to push messages to many users at the same time.
At the Moment pushing to 16500 Devices takes nearly 2 Minutes. That's unecaptable. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933836/ios-push-notification-how-many-can-i-send-from-my-server-in-a-minute) It says 9000 per sec should be passible. To Android I managed to push >20000 Messages in 30sec thas not optimal but ok.
Here is my code:

```
static function recursivSendToIOS($tokenArray, $payload){//tokenArray has max 500 entries
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    //ini_set('max_execution_time', '30');
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', Director::baseFolder().'/MyPemFile.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'mypassphrase');
    }
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 300, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    stream_set_blocking ( $fp , 0 );
    if (!$fp) {
        //Debug::log("Failed to connect $err $errstr\n");
        return;
    }
    $errortokenID = 0;
    foreach($tokenArray as $tokenID => $token){
        $apple_expiry = time() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        $msg = pack("C", 1) . pack("N", $token->ID) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token->Token)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $return = fwrite($fp, $msg);
        if((!$return) || ($return != strlen(bin2hex($msg))/2)){
            $errortokenID = $tokenID;
            break;
        }
        if(is_object($token) && $token->ID) {
            $token->delete();
            unset($deviceTokens[$token->ID]);
        }
    }
    usleep(100000); //when I reduce this I missing some Errors
    $error_response = self::checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);
    if(is_array($error_response)){
        $id = $error_response['identifier'];
        if(array_key_exists($id, $tokenArray)){
            $unvalid = $tokenArray[$id];
            if(is_object($unvalid) && $unvalid->ID) {
                $unvalid->delete();
                $offset = array_search($id, array_keys($tokenArray));
                unset($tokenArray[$unvalid->ID]);
                $offset++;
                $unsended = array_slice($tokenArray,$offset,null,true);//->limit($limit,);
                fclose($fp);
                self::recursivSendToIOS($unsended, $payload);
            }
        } else{
            fclose($fp);
            die();
        }
    } elseif($errortokenID) {
        $offset = array_search($errortokenID, array_keys($tokenArray));
        $unsended = array_slice($tokenArray,$offset,null,true);//->limit($limit,);
        fclose($fp);
        self::recursivSendToIOS($unsended, $payload);
    } else{
        Debug::log("Finish sending allTokens");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

static function checkAppleErrorResponse($fp) {

    //byte1=always 8, byte2=StatusCode, bytes3,4,5,6=identifier(rowID). Should return nothing if OK.
    $apple_error_response = fread($fp, 6);
    //NOTE: Make sure you set stream_set_blocking($fp, 0) or else fread will pause your script and wait forever when there is no response to be sent.

    if ($apple_error_response) {
        //unpack the error response (first byte 'command" should always be 8)
        $error_response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $apple_error_response);

        if ($error_response['status_code'] == '0') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '0-No errors encountered';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '1') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '1-Processing error';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '2') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '2-Missing device token';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '3') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '3-Missing topic';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '4') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '4-Missing payload';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '5') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '5-Invalid token size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '6') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '6-Invalid topic size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '7') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '7-Invalid payload size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '8') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '8-Invalid token';
            Debug::log("Invalid Token: ".$error_response['identifier']);
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '255') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '255-None (unknown)';
        } else {
            $error_response['status_code'] = $error_response['status_code'] . '-Not listed';
        }

        //Debug::log('<br><b>+ + + + + + ERROR</b> Response Command:<b>' . $error_response['command'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Identifier:<b>' . $error_response['identifier'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status:<b>' . $error_response['status_code'] . '</b><br>');
        //Debug::log('Identifier is the rowID (index) in the database that caused the problem, and Apple will disconnect you from server. To continue sending Push Notifications, just start at the next rowID after this Identifier.<br>');
        return $error_response;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The bottleneck here will most likely be PHP. Also 16500 in 120 seconds (137.5 per second) sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I havend noticed it before. So do you have any suggestions how to speed things up? My whole project is in php. So maybe store notifications in db and push them out with other software? What could I use for that?